# docker cache not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a simple docker image with the following dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2.7-onbuild

RUN python -m nltk.downloader 'punkt'
```

Whenever this image is built, it downloads the package from nltk. How can I cache it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as expected. I see two options:

- Mount a volume from your host with the cached NLTK data (wherever that sits)
- Create a base image (instead of `python:2.7-onbuild`) that has NLTK and the data preloaded and use this for your image. Try something like [this one](https://github.com/TrackMaven/docker-ntlk/blob/master/Dockerfile) perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

The clue is the 'onbuild' in the FROM line: the package is executing extra instructions, which may include something like the following:

```
ONBUILD ADD . /app/src
ONBUILD RUN /usr/local/bin/python-build --dir /app/src
```

causing whatever files are in your current directory, notably including any you've changed - e.g. your Dockerfile, unless you've excluded it with .dockerignore - to be pulled into your image, and then built.

It's unfortunate that Docker can't print the cause of cache misses in a meaningful way, but hashes have no concept of 'nearby'.